# Python Smtplib can't connect to SMTP server but openssl can

Tags: python, docker, openssl, smtp

I've been trying to send a simple mail from my server and I'm not sure why it's not working.

I am running a python app inside a Ubuntu docker container and from inside the container I can hit port 25 on the SMTP server using openssl command like so:
`openssl s_client -connect mymail.mymailserver.com:25`

However, when I attempt to connect to it with python Smtplib it just hangs forever. I've exposed port 25 on the container also.
`smtplib.SMTP('mymail.mymailserver.com', 25)`

Further, when I run the app on my desktop it sends the mail with no issue.

The only debug output from Smtplib is to show the connection attempt on the host and port.